# Calculating percentage between two dataframes concatenated into one dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation, percentage, calculation

If I have two dataframes (df1 and f2) and I join them into one dataframe (df3):

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Example dimensionality of df1, df2, and df3 are:

```
   df1 = (2, 1)
   df2 = (8, 1)
   df3 = (10, 1)
```

I would like to calculate the respective **length percentage** of df1 and df2 over df3. Output should be:

```
   df1 % over df3 = 20%
   df2 % over df3 = 80%
```

Is there a way to do this calculation in pandas?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output? Please create [mcve]

Comment: Percentage of what? Number of columns? Rows? One specific column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
print(f"{len(df1)/len(df3):.2f}%") # 0.20%
print(f"{len(df2)/len(df3):.2f}%") # 0.80%
```

Here `f` corresponds to [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

To get percentages use below:

```
print(f"{len(df1)/len(df3):.2%}") # 20.00%
print(f"{len(df2)/len(df3):.2%}") # 80.00%
```

From docs of [`mini string language`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

> `%` - *Percentage. Multiplies the number by 100 and displays in fixed ('f') format, followed by a percent sign.*

Comment: Thank you! however, when I print I get: 0.80% and 0.20%. How do I remove the 0 if I just want 80% and 20%?

Comment: And also, how do I put the .(dot) in between the integer and decimal places (e.g., 80.00%). Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! Last question: how do I convert an f-string to integer with four decimals? I tried **int(f"{len(df1)/len(df3):.2f}")** but I get error: **invalid literal for int()**

Comment: @Jack_T `f"{len(df1)/len(df3):.4f}"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I **print f"{len(df1)/len(df3):.4f}"**, I get the outcome like **'0.8000'**, which is fine. However, when I assign it to a variable (e.g., **p = f"{len(df1)/len(df3):.4f}"** and I call it, I get this error:  **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.80000**

Comment: I am assigning to a variable as I will need send it into a function. Any suggestion on how to do that? thanks!

Comment: @Jack_T looks have you have wrapped the f string inside `int` function.  Don't do that. I don't see the error.